# how to get MAC address using any browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, mac-address

I have already tried java applet it gets MAC address but now i want do it using javascript
I have an web app in which i want store user's MAC address using javascript. How i can find MAC address of user using any browser.

Comment: Not possible, browsers do not give any kind of access to a device's MAC address to client scripts

Answer (score 4):

Javascript always run in a Browser Sandbox for security reason. That's why it's not possible to get hardware information about the device it's running the script except from the once exposed by the Browser.

Mac Address it's not exposed :D

Comment: Is there any possible way to get MAC address..In any other language for all browse.

Comment: Hmm no, the only programming language known by browser is javascript. You may write a plug-in for the various browser to access these information but it's not transparent for the user because he has to download and install the plug-in